# How to load a bitmap from a resource file (.rc file)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

I am programming a simple game in visual studio and I have set up a resource file (.rc file) i am also using sdl2. I am wondering if there is a way to load or draw the bit maps located in the resource file. Thanks in advance

I am currently using this line:

```
HBITMAP hBtMpIMG = LoadBitmap((HINSTANCE)getModuleHandle(_T("Project 1.exe")), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
```

How would I render the hBtMpIMG using sdl2?

Comment: There are Windows API functions to load all possible resources from an embedded resource file into memory, and return a handle to it. In your case if you search a little you should find a function to load a bitmap from a resource and return a `HBITMAP` hhandle or similar. Then if you search a little more I'm sure you'll find something to convert that `HBITMAP` into something that SDL2 can use.

Comment: You probably need to convert `HBITMAP` to `BITMAP` in order to pass it to SDL. Also, SDL is a compatibility tool which is useful for programming in Windows and other operating systems. If you are using Windows specific functions then you might as well print the bitmap with Windows functions. Or stick to SDL and load the bitmap from file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the API: `LoadBitmap` to load a bitmap stored in the executable:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HBITMAP hBtMpBall = LoadBitmap((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BALL)); //Here we have to use the executable module to load our bitmap resource
        //this means that this resource "ball.bmp" is compiled and stored in the executable module"
        //however if you use loadimage you can ignore this module and makeit null because you are laoding from file

        if(!hBtMpBall)
            MessageBox(0,"ball.bmp not found!",0,0);
    }
    break;
```

- In a resource file: `.rc` you may have like this:

  ```
  #include "myres.h"

  IDB_BALL BITMAP DISCARDABLE "ball.bmp"
  ```

Comment: Will this still work if I am using SDL to create the window etc.?

Comment: You might as well add `DeleteObject(hBtMpBall)` to your example, it's necessary to avoid resource leak.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Yes to avoid running out of resources.